# Accessing last N-m records in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I do know how to access last N records from the table i.e,

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY auto_incremented_id DESC LIMIT N;
```

There are N records means and table records keep incrementing every day, each record having unique serial ID from 1 to N.
  now i want to retrieve 10 records of last N-10 rows.

please consider the example

```
  Record 1
  Record 2
  Record 3
  Record 4
  Record 5
  Record 6
  Record N-M
  Record N-2
  Record N-1
  Record N
```

How do i can retrieve ***N-2 to N-M*** rows

The solution required for an website -  **1st** page displays last 10 records, **2nd** Page displays last next 10 records from the reverse except rows are displayed in first page  and it goes on up to 1st record of the table.

Comment: Limit can take 2 args

Comment: What exactly is your RDBMS? MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: could you please show me with an example query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can play with ordering and your limit conditions

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * from table_name ORDER BY auto_incremented_id DESC LIMIT N) as temp ORDER BY auto_incremented_id ASC LIMIT M
```

assuming as you say a paging size of 10

first page:

```
SELECT * from as temp ORDER BY auto_incremented_id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

second page:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * from table_name ORDER BY auto_incremented_id DESC LIMIT 20) as temp ORDER BY auto_incremented_id ASC LIMIT 10;
```

third page:

```
SELECT * from (SELECT * from table_name ORDER BY auto_incremented_id DESC LIMIT 30) as temp ORDER BY auto_incremented_id ASC LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 3):

For dynamically limiting the output rows you can use inline views (as MySQL doesn't support common table expressions using `WITH` clause). An example code is as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id, name
               , @i := @i + 1 as result
          FROM table_name
               , (select @i := 0) temp
      ORDER BY id) v
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(id) AS M FROM table_name) w
 WHERE result BETWEEN w.m-2 AND w.m;
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27b83/1).

Comment: as i was mentioned N keeps incrementing and decrementing as records are added and deleted so how do i can determine the N

Comment: Oh so that's your problem... Just a few mins. I will edit my answer. I hope you can convert the ROW_NUMBER from Oracle syntax to MySQL's.

Comment: The question is for MySQL not Oracle.  I'll remove the downvote if you write a MySQL version :)

Comment: @Andomar and Bhanu: Answer edited. Please see the fiddle also.

Comment: your answer worked well for my problem but i choose @Stefano Crespi answer because it is easy quite simple, i don't have 15+ reputation to up-vote your answer.